# Как правильно сделать запрос к базе данных в Django ORM

Tags: python, django, база-данных, orm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать запросы к базе данных, чтобы получить внуков и правнуков?

Есть следующая модель пользователя:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), unique=True, db_index=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(_('ФИО'), max_length=255, blank=True, db_index=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('является активным'), default=True)
    father = models.ForeignKey("CustomUser", related_name='sons', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('отец'))
    
    ....
```

У каждого сына есть 1 отец. У каждого отца есть несколько сыновей.
Мне нужно прописать для модели свойства для получения детей, внуков и правнуков.

С первым проблем нет:

```
@property
def get_children(self):
    return CustomUser.objects.filter(father_id=self.id).only('id', )
```

А как быть с внуками и правнуками?

```
@property
def get_grandchildren(self):
    ....

@property
def get_great_grandchildren(self):
    ....
```

Можно было бы взять детей и пройтись по каждому циклом, получив внуков. Затем аналогичным образом пройтись по внукам и получить правнуков. Но я понимаю, что на каждую итерацию цикла делать запрос к БД - плохая затея.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с оптимальными запросами.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property
def children(self):
    return CustomUser.objects.filter(father=self)

@property
def grandchildren(self):
    return CustomUser.objects.filter(father__in=self.children)

@property
def great_grandchildren(self):
    return CustomUser.objects.filter(father__in=self.grandchildren)
```

Я убрал `get_` из имени свойств, так так это более распостраненная  практика.

Кроме того я сделал, чтоб эти свойства возвращали объекты, а не их идентификаторы. Это более универсально. Если нужны идентификаторы, то можно получить их уже из результата так `user.children.only("id")`

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Как говорится, всё гениальное просто. Я как дурак пытался составить сложный многоуровневый запрос.